# How to reward an answer that isn't my accepted answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, bounty

I asked the question [Handling critical hits easily when using average damage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124309/handling-critical-hits-easily-when-using-average-damage) and literally every answer is good. I've up-voted them all accordingly.

For context, I accepted Rubiksmoose's answer, then later Glen_b posted an answer that is mathematically equivalent but expressed in a more intuitive fashion. After some comment exchanges, Rubiksmoose updated their answer to mention the more intuitive phrasing (with attribution to Glen_b) and Glen_b also revised their post to be more supported.

I still like all answers. Those two answers, Rubiksmoose's and Glen_b's, are the most helpful. When all is said and done, Rubiksmoose's answer is still the most helpful for me, but I feel like Glen_b's deserves more than the few up-votes it has gotten (which I suspect are just due to the late-to-the-party effect where early answers get more up-votes and later answers go unseen).

Is it possible/viable/sensible for me to un-accept Rubiksmoose's answer, start a bounty, award the bounty to Glen_b when the bounty is finished, and then accept Rubiksmoose's answer, so I can mark which answer was truly most helpful to me while also rewarding Glen_b?

If not, is there something else I should do instead? Maybe the obvious answer is to just accept Glen_b's instead, but I think that would be a little disingenuous because it doesn't match how I feel about the two answers, whereas the bounty idea does.

For reference, I've never done a bounty before. I read over the SE page about bounties, but I'm afraid to pull the trigger if this idea is bad.

Answer (score 8):

Awarding a bounty of the “reward existing answer” variety to another answer you like is a fine idea. You should be able to do so without fiddling the accept checkmark — I don’t believe starting a bounty is affected by the checkmark. (It only affects awarding, and only if you forget to award it before it expires.)

You can award a bounty the day after you start it, so you don’t need to wait the full week.

Comment: Cool. The bounty link doesn't show up for me unless I un-accept the answer, but that might be because I have 23 hours to go before I can start one. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: The bounty link will not show up when any of the following is true: the question is less than 48 hours old, you already have 3 other active bounties (you can't have more than this active at once), or another bounty is already active on the question. It's likely the first case you were noticing here.

Comment: Hm! It’s probably just the delay for new questions, yes.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll check back in a day. I appreciate the clarifications.

Comment: Also, I just confirmed that by checking one of my older questions that has an accepted answer. Indeed, the link to create a bounty shows up there.